# Direct3D 11 Constant buffer too small......

Tags: directx-11, hlsl, direct3d11

```
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: The size of the Constant Buffer at slot 0 of the Vertex Shader unit is too small (16 bytes provided, 64 bytes, at least, expected).` `This is OK, as out-of-bounds reads are defined to return 0. It is also possible the developer knows the missing data will not be used anyway.` `This is only a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a sufficiently large Constant Buffer for what the shader expects.`  `[ EXECUTION WARNING #351: DEVICE_DRAW_CONSTANT_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL]
```

P.S. Could  it be  a reason  why my  DDS  Cube texture  does  not  draw  in G-Buffer ?! It is just  a warning  but whole  day i  am sticking with  this  any help.

Comment: This means your constant buffer sizes that you bind at runtime do not match the constant buffer declarations in your shaders.